# Complex SQL Query visualizer

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, sql-server

Is there a tool (gratis), that helps developer to understand or helps to visualize the complex queries (involving `JOINS`, `GROUP BY`).

I know about the [snowflakesjoins](https://snowflakejoins.com/) service which provides visualizer upto 800 characters but that is quite short.

It doesn't really matter if it can access the database or not. All I want is: if the SQL query is supplied, it should give some sort of visualization to understand the complexity.

I am looking for something that runs on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Python based reverse snowflake:
http://revj.sourceforge.net

Comment: funny thing is, it brings back to snowflakejoins.com site. :)

Answer (score 3):

This online [SQL parser](https://sqldep.com) visualises data flows and table joins in SQL statements -- see [demo](https://app.sqldep.com/queryscope/demo/). It comes with a free tier.

*disclaimer: I am co-founder of SQLdep (somebody who got too lazy to manually analyse SQL) :)*

Comment: Well, the tool looks good but it seems like heavily priced for anyone  even to consider.

Comment: **QueryScope** (query visualiser) is $15/month. **QueryFlow** is heavily priced as it aims at DWH teams with 1m+ lines of SQL code.

Comment: okay.that was missing piece.