# Visualizing SQL query from .sql file

Tags: data-visualization, sql

I have a folder of independent `.sql`-files that are used by a FastAPI application to request data from the Oracle Database.

Each file includes a variable (e.g. `:plot_fsk`) that is later on modified using a function that changes variable in SQL query by means of the `sqlalchemy.sql.text` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268050/execute-sql-from-file-in-sqlalchemy/63442962#63442962).

Here is the content of a single `.sql`-file

```
SELECT CONCAT(A_AA88888.AFL, ' m²') AS PLOTAREA
FROM DB_UTM.A_AA88888 A_AA88888
WHERE A_AA88888.FSK = :plot_fsk
```

For my documentation I would like to have the graphic representation of those `.sql`-files in a neat and user-friendly schematic manner. Is there any automatic approach to implement this task?

In that visualization I would like to include:

- all the tables names
- all the attributes that are requested in `SELECT` and `WHERE` with their original names
- all the relations between tables, like different `JOIN`s etc.
- `ORDER BY` can be neglected

So, the above SQL query will look like:

[image: fancy _diagram]

I have seen some articles but none of them mention a visualization from an individual file (when the entire Database *should not* considered):

- [Complex SQL Query visualizer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35598/complex-sql-query-visualizer#)
- [Tool to Visualize SQL Database Schema](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/tool-to-visualize-sql-database-schema)
- [Good tool to visualise database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433071/good-tool-to-visualise-database-schema)
- [5 Tools to visualize database schemas](http://www.codediesel.com/data/5-tools-to-visualize-database-schemas/)
- [The 11 Best Data Visualization Tools for SQL](https://chartio.com/learn/business-intelligence/the-11-best-data-visualization-tools-for-sql/)
- [Reverse Snowflake Joins (abbreviated as revj)](http://revj.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what needs to be in the visualization and what doesn't? For example, you write:  "So, the above SQL query will look like:" I'd argue that in a general sense, that is not true, as there is information in the SQL query (such as the fact that only the AFL column is projected to the result set, and renamed and concatenated with a constant at that) that is not hinted at in the visualization sample you provide.